# What is "small" collection or "huge" collection

Tags: collections, count, size

another day, another problem :) 
Since I woke up today I'm wondering about numbers. My experience does not allow me to answear my questions: 
What is the small collection? what is the medium size collection? what is the huge collection?
I mean where're the lines? ex. between 0 to XX elements is small collection and so on... I read many articles, blog posts about using collections and almost everywhere we can read "this solution is good for small collections" etc. and I ask: What does that mean? I know there's no hard lines but I think we can name it more or less :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no hard lines, because it depends on **many** different things.

In some situations the size of the objects stored in the collection matter, in others it doesn't.

In some situations the CPU/memory is fast enough that "small" can be as large as a million, in others a few dozens is already "mid-sized".

*Personally* and from *my* experience in my *specific* field I'd guesstimate these rules-of-thumb:

- a small collections has at most 10-20 elements
- a few hundered elements make a medium-sized collection
- a collection with more than thousand elements is large-ish

Again: this is **very** subjective and situational.

Often "this works for small collections" is a synonym for "this has a non-linear runtime over the size of the collection" or (more specifically) "this is O(n^2)".